# Efficient way of reading a file into an std::vector<char>?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I'd like to avoid unnecessary copies. I'm aiming for something along the lines of:

```
std::ifstream testFile( "testfile", "rb" );
std::vector<char> fileContents;
int fileSize = getFileSize( testFile );
fileContents.reserve( fileSize );
testFile.read( &fileContents[0], fileSize );
```

(which doesn't work because `reserve` doesn't actually insert anything into the vector, so I can't access `[0]`).

Of course, `std::vector<char> fileContents(fileSize)` works, but there is an overhead of initializing all elements (`fileSize` can be rather big). Same for `resize()`.

This question is not so much about how important that overhead would be. Rather, I'm just curious to know if there's another way.

Comment: If you want to avoid the reallocation cost required by `push_back` _and_ you want to avoid the cost of zeroing the buffer required by using `resize`, don't use a `std::vector` at all:  use a `boost::scoped_array` or something similar.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The canonical form is this:

```
#include<iterator>
// ...

std::ifstream testFile("testfile", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> fileContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(testFile)),
                               std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

If you are worried about reallocations then reserve space in the vector:

```
#include<iterator>
// ...

std::ifstream testFile("testfile", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> fileContents;
fileContents.reserve(fileSize);
fileContents.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(testFile),
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Comment: Won't that do reallocations while the vector is growing? (Since the iterators might not support subtraction, the constructor cannot determine the size in advance.)

Comment: Yes, it would. If that's really a concern, then reserve and use `std::copy()`. Updated.

Comment: In the second example, `reserve` needs to be `resize`, no?

Comment: But `resize()` would initialize the elements. That's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Yes, it is. As written, the code is incorrect because `fileContents.begin()` is not dereferenceable (it is equal to `fileContents.end()`).  An STL implementation with debugging support (like the Visual C++ 2010 STL) should raise an assertion when executing this code.

Comment: Better late than never: simplified the code a little. Remove the `<algorithm>` dependency by replacing the `std::copy()` call with `std::vector::assign()`. Also, for `std::ifstream` there's no need to pass `std::ios::in` to the constructor. The constructor knows that.

Comment: `(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(testFile))`: Why the extra parentness?

Comment: @cubuspl42 Because of the most vexing parse.

Comment: @wilhelmtell is this (the 2nd option) more efficient than simply doing `vector<char> fileContents(fileSize);` and `testFile.read(&fileContents[0], fileSize);` ? Judging from a quick test (150MB file), using read seems quite more efficient in terms of speed

Answer (score 5):

If you want true zero-copy reading, that is, to eliminate copying from kernel to user space, just map the file into memory. Write your own mapped file wrapper or use one from `boost::interprocess`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to read each element but don't want to load it all into the `fileContents`, correct?
I personally don't think this would make unnecessary copies because open files multiple times would decrease performance more. Read once into a `fileContents`vector is a reasonable solution in this case.

Comment: I did not mean to vote this down, but it is locked in.  If you edit the answer I can / will remove the down vote.