# Using std::ifstream, std::istream_iterator and std::copy is not reading entire file

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following code which I have been using on a 188 byte file:

```
std::ifstream is("filename", std::ios::binary);

std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
std::istream_iterator<uint8_t> i_input(is);
std::copy(i_input, std::istream_iterator<uint8_t>(),
          std::back_inserter(buffer));

std::cout << buffer.size();
```

However it is only reading 186 bytes of the 188 bytes.

I have confirmed the file size in a hexeditor as well as with `ls -al`.

Comment: I can confirm this. Have file of 368 bytes, the vector size is only 312. GCC version is `gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know why, but by default that seems to skip whitespace. You need to disable that with `noskipws`:

```
is >> std::noskipws;
```

Comment: That was it for me. Though I find it weird that the stream should skip whitespace when opened in binary mode.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That has nothing to do with binary modes. You're using *formatted extraction*, which does all sorts of mangling and skipping. Arguably, formatted-extracting into a `char` must be the worst way to read in a raw file!

Comment: @KerrekSB You're right. Must have been to early for me to think properly I guess.

Comment: Oooh! That makes sense, frustrating that it wasn't documented anywhere I was reading.

Answer (score 9):

What are the last two bytes? Also, you don't really need a `istream_iterator` for reading binary data like this. That's overkill and probably slower than using `streambuf`.

See this example from [wilhelmtell's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761529/efficient-way-of-reading-a-file-into-an-stdvectorchar/4761779#4761779):

```
#include<iterator>
// ...

std::ifstream testFile("testfile", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> fileContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(testFile)),
                               std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I will switch to this method.