# Something like istream::getline() but with alternative delim characters?

Tags: c++, getline, text-parsing, istream

What's the cleanest way of getting the effect of `istream::getline(string, 256, '\n' OR ';')`?

I know it's quite straightforward to write a loop, but I feel that I might be missing something. Am I?

What I used:

```
while ((is.peek() != '\n') && (is.peek() != ';'))
    stringstream.put(is.get());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to have multiple "line endings". What you can do is read the line with e.g. `std::getline` and put it in an `std::istringstream` and use `std::getline` (with the `';'` separator) in a loop on the `istringstream`.

Although you could check the [Boost iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) library to see it it has functionality for it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's quite nice! 
I wrote a loop that std::stringstream.put():ed every char until it found '\n' or ';', and then used stringstream.str() to get the string.

Answer (score 3):

There's [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).
For more complex scenarios one might try splitting [istream_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) or [istreambuf_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) with [boost split](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.split_hpp) or [regex_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_iterator.html) ([here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761529/efficient-way-of-reading-a-file-into-an-stdvectorchar/4761779#4761779) of using stream iterators).

Comment: `std::getline` is good because it has an overload for `std::string` which makes string I/O much, much easier (at least in my opinion).

Comment: `std::getline` doesn't help in this case when the OP want multiple line endings/separators.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working implementation:

```
enum class cascade { yes, no };
std::istream& getline(std::istream& stream, std::string& line, const std::string& delim, cascade c = cascade::yes){
    line.clear();
    std::string::value_type ch;
    bool stream_altered = false;
    while(stream.get(ch) && (stream_altered = true)){
        if(delim.find(ch) == std::string::npos)
            line += ch;
        else if(c == cascade::yes && line.empty())
            continue;
        else break;
    }
    if(stream.eof() && stream_altered) stream.clear(std::ios_base::eofbit);
    return stream;
}
```

The `cascade::yes` option collapses consecutive delimiters found. With `cascade::no`, it will return an empty string for each a second consecutive delimeter found.

Usage:

```
const std::string punctuation = ",.';:?";
std::string words;
while(getline(istream_object, words, punctuation))
    std::cout << word << std::endl;
```

See its usage <kbd>[**Live on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dc8a457964e727d)</kbd>

A more generic version will be [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1457f0cb360ea9f)