# Shortest way to read Textfile to String

Tags: c++, string, file, text, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to slurp a file into a std::string in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c)

I assumed there would be a question like this already, but I couldn't find one. So here goes my question.

What is the shortest way to read a whole text file into a string? I only want to use features of the newest C++ standard and standard libraries.

I think there must be an one liner for this common task!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4761779/942596 this links gives a nice method. replace vector with string and it still works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably this:

```
std::ifstream fin("filename");
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << fin.rdbuf();
std::string file_contents = oss.str();
```

There's also this:

```
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> begin(fin), end;
std::string file_contents(begin, end);
```

Some might suggest this, but I prefer to type `istreambuf_iterator<char>` only once.

```
std::string file_contents(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{fin}, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Answer (score 1):

To read a file into a `std::string` using one statement (whether it fit on one line depends on the length of you lines...) looks like this:

```
std::string value{
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(
        std::ifstream("file.txt").rdbuf()),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()};
```

The approach is unfortunately often not as fast as using an extra `std::ostringstream` is (although it should really be faster...).