# How to directly read a huge chunk of memory into std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, placement-new

I have a huge contiguous array `x` that I `fread` from a file.

How do I drop this chunk into a `std::vector<>`?  In other words, I prefer to have the result to be in `std::vector<>` rather than the array, but I want the resultant C++ code to be as efficient as this plain C-version which drops the chunk right into the array.

From searching around, I think I may have to use placement-new in some form, but I'm uncertain about the sequence of calls and ownership issues.  Also, do I need to worry about alignment issues?

I am testing for with `T = unsigned`, but I expect a reasonable solution to work for any POD struct.

```
using T = unsigned;
FILE* fp = fopen( outfile.c_str(), "r" );
T* x = new T[big_n];
fread( x, sizeof(T), big_n, fp );

// how do I get x into std::vector<T> v
// without calling a gazillion push_backs() or copies ?!?

delete[] x;
fclose( fp );
```

Comment: Any reason your not reading the file directly to the vector?

Comment: @ahenderson - because I didn't realize that you could - Joachim's answer below looks good

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use the `std::vector` [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) which sets the size of the vector, and use [`std::vector::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) to get a pointer to allocated memory.

Keeping with your use of `fread`:

```
std::vector<T> x(big_n);
fread(x.data(), sizeof(T), big_n, fp);
```

---

As noted by others, using `fread` if the type `T` is not a [POD type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189821/734069) will most likely not work. You can then use C++ streams and [`std::istreambuf_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) to read the file into the vector. However this have the drawback that it loops over all items in the file, and if `big_n` is as big as it sounds then this might be a performance problem.

---

However, if the file truly is big, I rather recommend using [memory mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) to read the file.

Comment: That's a simple solution, but not quite "as efficient as this plain C-version" since it initialises the vector with zero values.

Comment: If T will ever be a non-POD, you'd need to call the destructors manualy before you overwrite `.data()`, right?

Comment: @jrok If T is anything but a character type, you can't reliably read it with `fread`.  And if T isn't a POD, it's almost certain that you can't read it.

Comment: I actually tried `mmap` before this.  In fact, because I want really big chunk of the file at once, `fread` is actually faster.  But I think for lots of random/small reads, `mmap` would be preferable.

Comment: @kfmfe04 No, mmap shoould be faster for lots of data since it allocates whole vector at once without reallocations. Maybe you did something wrong

Comment: The only thing i dislike about this solution is to break the `std::vector` encapsulation by accessing _private_ memory managed by the vector via the `data` method.

Comment: @BЈовић I retried `mmap` with Joachim's solution combined with `memcpy` and it's running much faster than before - you're right: something was off with the earlier version.

Comment: @kfmfe04 Good. Now try with some casting and without memcpy

Comment: @BЈовић unfortunately, I need the `memcpy` so I can do a `std::sort` as part of an external sort - so I need to flush the results to disk afterwards.

Comment: @kfmfe04 `std::sort` can sort normal raw arrays as well, which is what the memory pointer returned by `mmap` can bee seen as.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, `data()` is a _public_ member, added in C++11 specifically to allow you to do this. You could already do it with `&x[0]` in C++03 anyway. The memory layout of a `std::vector` is part of its interface.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg @BЈовић I appreciate your suggestions: I ended up using `mmap` in conjunction with `std::transform` to shape the data the way I needed it.  ty.

Comment: @JonathanWakely `vector::data()` maybe is _for_ this functionality, but, I feel troubled using it. This method returns a pointer to the internal memory presumably managed by the class, IMO is insecure; after calling `data` you can read/write into the returned pointer, pass the pointer to functions, store the pointer into another object and sometimes you'll not sure about the lifetime of the memory pointed by this value. Yes, doing this stuff is a bad practice but `vector::data()` is a _public_ member and allow you to do this.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, the same is true if you have a pointer to an array, or to any object. If you store that pointer somewhere it might be unsafe because the object went out of scope.  You need to be careful, yes, but then this is C++ :) With great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: @JonathanWakely The fact is that you're right, but I feel troubled "_breaking encapsulations_" anyways :P

Answer (score 0):

This will read the file into a vector using

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include<iterator>
// ...

std::ifstream testFile("testfile", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<unsigned char> fileContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<unsigned char>(testFile)),
                           std::istreambuf_iterator<unsigned char>());
```

This answer comes from a previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4761779/942596

Comment: +1 for an interesting alternative - I suppose this should also work for any `std::vector<POD>`?  I'll try it out.

Comment: @kfmfe04 That's a good question I have never tested that. Let me know if you can.

Comment: This code doesn't work, you can't use `istreambuf_iterator<unsigned char>` to read from `basic_istream<char>` (the character types don't match). Also, in C++11 the second iterator can be written simply `{}`

Comment: `istreambuf_iterator<unsigned char> + 5` is not working. So it is impossible to read chunk of file using this method