# How to read a .txt file using c-strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, fstream, ifstream

I'm working on a project for school and I need to read in text from a file.

Sounds easy peasy, except my professor put a restriction on the project: **NO STRINGS**
("No string data types or the string library are allowed.")

I've been getting around this problem by using char arrays; however, I'm not sure how to use char arrays to read in from a file.

---

This is an **example** from another website on how to read in a file **with** strings.

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

The important line here is `while ( getline (myfile,line) );`

`getline` accepts an ifstream and a **string** (not char array).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what's the result do you need if meet NO STRINGS,  just an empty string "" or nothing but exit?

Comment: @vinllen I'll quote the rule here : "No string data types or the string library are allowed."

Comment: If your instructor actually put that in all caps and doesn't explicitly state you can't use `std::vector` I'd use `std::vector`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761529/efficient-way-of-reading-a-file-into-an-stdvectorchar

Comment: what does the text file contain? It is rather important because if it contains numbers, then one does not need strings, if it contains text, then one should use char*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cin.getline`. Refer to this site for the format: [cin.getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/).

You can write something like this:

```
ifstream x("example.txt");
char arr[105];
while (x.getline(arr,100,'\n')){
    cout << arr << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ifstream` has a method named `get()` that reads the contents of the file into a `char` array. `get()` takes, as parameters, a pointer to the array, and the size of the array; then fills the array up to the given size, if possible.

After `get()` returns, use the `gcount()` method to determine how many characters have been read.

You can use then, and a simple logical loop, to repeatedly read the contents of the file, in `size`-chunks, into an array, and collect all the chunks read into a single array, or a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `int i = 0; while (scanf("%c", &str[i ++]) != EOF)` to judge the end of text input. `str` is the char array include newline which you wanted, and `i` is the input size.

You can also use `while(cin.getline())` to read per line every loop in C++ style:
`istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );` just like below:

```
const int SIZE = 100;
const int MSIZE = 100;
int main() {
    freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
    char str[SIZE][MSIZE];
    int i = -1;
    while (cin.getline(str[++ i], MSIZE)) {
        printf("input string is [%s]\n", str[i]);
    }    
}
```

Comment: where exactly would the `istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );` go? I'm a little confused