# Copy iterator range to vector without duplication

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to read a file to a vector and I got to this nice [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761529/efficient-way-of-reading-a-file-into-an-stdvectorchar), which contains 2 methods of doing this.(I will ignore non-important lines)

```
std::ifstream testFile("testfile", std::ios::binary);

std::vector<char> fileContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(testFile)),
                               std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

std::vector<char> fileContents;
fileContents.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(testFile),
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

My code (C++ 11) suits a lot better for the second approach (I need the vector constructed very early), but from CPP documentation it seems that in the first solution, the constructor will add emplace-constructed values, compared to the "assign" method which will create new objects and add them to the vector, thus making copies.

Is there a solution to assign the vector later but without making copies?

Thanks

Comment: You can keep a pointer to `fileContents`. So that you can create the object later. This may defeat the purpose of 'micro-optimisation'. Not the best way, but there I shared it.

Comment: Since you are talking about chars, it doesn't matter if your move (or emplace) or copy.

Comment: vectors make copies. If you are really worried about memory, you can make a vector of pointers, which will later point to the strings.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, yes, a pointer it's a possible solution, at the moment I am using these lines to add to it later, which I really don't like.          `for (auto it = (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)); it != std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(); it++)
        {
            file_contents.emplace_back(*it);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can you swap your vector with a new one:

```
std::vector<char> fileContents;
std::vector<char> newContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(testFile)),
                               std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
std::swap(fileContents, newContents);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the standard given a container `a<T>` for

```
a.assign(i,j)
```

to work

> Each iterator in the range [i,j) shall be dereferenced exactly once.

and eventually

> Replaces elements in 'a' with a copy of [i, j).

So in summary you cannot assign the vector later without making copies.

Comment: Yes, I understood that, that's why I searched for another solution.I am not sure if this make duplicates also: `std::move(std::istream_iterator<char>(ifs),std::istream_iterator<char>(), std::back_inserter(file_contents));`

Comment: Looking at your original query I am not really sure why this is a concern. You aren't really creating duplicates in-memory. The source is on persistent storage while the vector is the only copy in-memory.

Comment: I am not sure, but I thought that there are 2 copies (besides the persistent storage): the ifstream and the vector.

Comment: The stream is transient. You will need to close it once the transfer is done to the vector.